# Limit comparison test how to choose $b_n$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{4n^2+1}\tag{1}$$

i would like to find out if this series convergent or not 
so i use Limit comparison test and choose  $a_n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ why do i need to choose $b_n$ as $\frac{1}{n}$ because at the end $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent and whole $a_n$ is divergent.???? why can't i choose  $b_n$  as $\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Because $a_n$ is not (eventually) less than $\frac{1}{n^2}$. And, yes, the summation of $a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: does it have to do something with $\frac {2n}{4n^2}$=$\frac {1}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, the limit comparison test shows that they both diverge. By the way, the upper limit should be $\infty$..

Comment: I think you want the $n$ above the sum to be $\infty$.

Comment: hmm found similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617319/selection-of-b-n-in-limit-comparison-test-for-checking-convergence-of-a-series?rq=1
do i delete this one?

Comment: When $n$ is big, $\frac{2n-1}{4n^2+1}$ behaves very much like $\frac{1}{2n}$. Hence it is reasonable to try a limit comparison with $\frac{1}{2n}$ or with $\frac{1}{n}$.